# Internal Hosting of SSL Certificates

Tags: iis, amazon-web-services, ssl-certificate

I have a number of SSL certificates (*.mydomain.com, myotherdomain.com), currently when setting up new environments / products I am manually adding the SSL certificate to store on the new server and then binding it to the site.

I would like to do this programatically, therefore I need to have the SSL certificates available to my code. My question is, what is the best practise regarding hosting and accessing SSL certificates. They would be hosted in AWS, but I am concerned about how to securely access them from the application that will install them on the servers.

I am thinking creating an API that is authenticated against a key on the server hosting the SSL certificate is the way to go, but am just wondering if there is a better solution or if anyone else has accomplished something similar, perhaps accessing AWS Certificate Manager using their API?

Many Thanks,

Comment: How many servers, and how often are they renewed? I use ACME and Let's Encrypt, certificate renewal is fully automatic, but not initial setup or installation.

Comment: I'd never heard of ACME before, looks interesting I'll give it a look, thanks!

Comment: Tutorial: https://www.photographerstechsupport.com/tutorials/hosting-wordpress-on-aws-tutorial-part-5-free-https-https2-for-wordpress-using-lets-encrypt-aws/